# logical OR operator vs bitwise OR operator

Tags: java

does anyone know why:

```
if (false && true || true) {
       System.out.println("True");
} else {
      System.out.println("False");
}
```

Print "**True**"

```
if (false && true | true) {
           System.out.println("True");
    } else {
          System.out.println("False");
    }
```

Print "**False**"

Comment: There was a correct answer here by colin that got downvoted like crazy. I don't want the same fate so I'll post it as a comment: & and | in a boolean context are not bitwise operators, but eager boolean operators (there's no short-circuit, both sides will always be evaluated) . See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation#Support_in_common_programming_languages

Comment: The strange thing though is that I can't find any sun official document where | and & are referenced as logical operators (but it's part of the SCJP6 exam)

Comment: @seanizer: There's still a correct answer here. (Two of them, in fact.) :-) Whether they're bitwise or not on booleans isn't really the point *here*, the `|` is higher precedence regardless and that's why the OP is seeing the behavior he/she is asking about.

Comment: @t.j. I am not saying your answers aren't correct. And you are using the same wording Sun does, too. But Colin's answer was more accurate in terms of wording, and I didn't understand the downvotes.

Comment: @seanizer: The downvotes seemed inappropriate to me too, though again I don't think the bitwise-vs-purely-logical thing was relevant and did, to me, confuse the issue. You apply a bitwise logical operator to a single bit (which is, conceptually, what booleans are meant to be) and you get a...logical operator. That's the only "special" thing about `|` and `&` in a boolean context AFAIK.

Comment: @tj technically you are right, of course: see http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/tools/javac/code/Symtab.java.html lines 571 and 632 (you can see it's the same symbol as the bitwise int operator). But semantically it's an insufficient taxonomy, & and && are both boolean operators, one with and one without short circuit evaluation. BTW the && operator is also bitwise, of course (just as the & is also logical).

Answer (score 21):

In the first case && has higher precedence than || operator so the expression is evaluated as `if ( (false && true) || true )` and you get True.

In the second case bitwise OR operator has higher precedence than && so the expression is evaluated as `if ( false && ( true | true ) )` and you get False.

Comment: It is not a bitwise operator in this context. The whole expression if ( false && ( true | true ) ) will be evaluated. Want some proof (of both statements)?

Comment: @Pawel: Whether it's bitwise or not doesn't really matter in the context of the OP's question. `|` still takes precedence over `&&`, and so the first operation is `true | true` which is `true`, which then feeds into `false && true`, which is of course `false`. This whole thing of whether `|` is being bitwise when applied to booleans is beside the point and mostly semantic in any case (a bitwise logical operator applied to just one bit -- which is what a `boolean` conceptually is -- is a...logical operator!). :-)

Comment: && and & are both bitwise and both logical in a boolean context, but && has a higher precedence than & (or |)

Comment: @seanizer: *"...but && has a higher precedence than & (or |)"* Is that a typo? Both `&` and `|` have a higher precedence than `&&`, see the link in my answer and this proof: http://pastie.org/1155571 It's why the OP is seeing what he/she is seeing.

Comment: @t.j. yes, it was a typical pre-lunch-I-am-too-hungry-typo. Sorry

Answer (score 18):

Because of [operator precedence](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). In your first example, the `&&` is done first, and then the `||`. But the bitwise OR has higher precedence, so in your second example the `|` is done first, then the `&&`.