# "Single stepping until exit from function objc_exception_throw, which has no line number information." when using enumeration in objective c

Tags: objective-c, exception, enumeration

I found a similar question that threw the same exception, but it wasn't helpful. No one answered: [Getting "Single stepping until exit from function CALayerGetDelegate, which has no line number information." in iphone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547240/getting-single-stepping-until-exit-from-function-calayergetdelegate-which-has)

Sample parameter that works when program is `aa+a+`

Sample parameter that causes break when method called again by parameter program is `aa+a+a`. Why?

Here's my code:

```
+(NSSet *)variablesUsedInsideProgram:(id)program
{

    NSMutableSet *variablesUsed = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:program];
    //put the program into a mutable set then pop off everything else that is !a,!b,!c

    id objectReferenceFromVariablesUsed = nil;
    for(objectReferenceFromVariablesUsed in variablesUsed) //breaks here
    {
        if (!([objectReferenceFromVariablesUsed isEqual:@"a"] | [objectReferenceFromVariablesUsed isEqual:@"b"] | [objectReferenceFromVariablesUsed isEqual:@"c"]))
        {
            [variablesUsed removeObject:objectReferenceFromVariablesUsed];
        }
    }
    return [variablesUsed copy];
}
```

DEBUG print out statements I get:

```
(gdb) po program<__NSArrayI 0x68a7a00>(a,a,+,a,+,a)
```

so I know my program pushed in variable `a`

```
(gdb) po variablesUsed
{(
    "+",
    a
)}
```

Unique values from program when added to NSMutableSet

What I know that is happening:

> objectReferenceFromVariablesUsed = +, then it gets popped off the Set
>
> (gdb) po variablesUsed {( a )}
>
> Goes back into the loop then breaks. Gets Error Message "Single stepping until exit from function objc_exception_throw, which has no line number information. Catchpoint 2 (exception thrown).

Does anybody know what might be causing this?

Comment: Is the bitwise or (|) compared to the logical or (||) in the if-statement intentional? See this question for a description of the difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698741/logical-or-operator-vs-bitwise-or-operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED!

> +(NSSet *)variablesUsedInsideProgram:(id)program
>   {

```
NSMutableSet *variablesUsed = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:program];
NSMutableSet *variablesUsed1 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:program]; **//HERE**
//put the program into a mutable set then pop off everything else that is !a,!b,!c

id objectReferenceFromVariablesUsed = nil;
for(objectReferenceFromVariablesUsed in variablesUsed) //breaks here
{
    if (!([objectReferenceFromVariablesUsed isEqual:@"a"] | [objectReferenceFromVariablesUsed isEqual:@"b"] | [objectReferenceFromVariablesUsed isEqual:@"c"]))
    {

        [variablesUsed1 removeObject:objectReferenceFromVariablesUsed];
    }
}
return [variablesUsed1 copy];
```

}

Answer (score 2):

**Original answer (and the useful comment by Walt):**

You are modifying the set while enumerating over it

> which is not allowed in Objective-C's Fast Enumeration. – [Walt Sellers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263824/walt-sellers) Mar 1 at 8:22

---

**Update:**

## What to do instead:

The better approach would be to add the objets that should be removed to a new set and update the original by removing all objects in the new set using [-minusSet:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutableset_Class/Reference/NSMutableSet.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableSet/minusSet:) (documentation below). Note from the documentation that *the objects are removed in place* (a new set is *not* returned).

> ### minusSet:
>
> Removes each object in another given set from the receiving set, if present.
>
> ```
> - (void)minusSet:(NSSet *)otherSet
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *otherSet*
>
> The set of objects to remove from the receiving set.

---

### Actual implementation (modification of your code)

To remove all objects that aren't either "a", "b" or "c", you would first create a new NSMutableSet (objectsToBeRemoved) for adding the objects that should be removed to. While enumerating the original set (variablesUsed) and finding an object that should be removed, add it to the new set (objectsToBeRemoved). After the enumeration, remove all the objects that should be removed by calculating the the original set minus the set of objects to remove.

```
+(NSSet *)variablesUsedInsideProgram:(id)program
{
    NSMutableSet *variablesUsed = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:program];
    //put the program into a mutable set then pop off everything else that is !a,!b,!c
    
    NSMutableSet *objectsToBeRemoved = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    
    id objectReferenceFromVariablesUsed = nil;
    for(objectReferenceFromVariablesUsed in variablesUsed)
    {
        if (!([objectReferenceFromVariablesUsed isEqual:@"a"] || 
              [objectReferenceFromVariablesUsed isEqual:@"b"] || 
              [objectReferenceFromVariablesUsed isEqual:@"c"]))
        {
            [objectsToBeRemoved addObject:objectReferenceFromVariablesUsed];
        }
    }
    
    return [[variablesUsed minusSet:objectsToBeRemoved] copy];
}
```

Comment: which is not allowed in Objective-C's Fast Enumeration.